# Не работает калькулятор C++

Tags: c++

[image]

При попытке ввести любые числа выдает 0

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1248725/edit))

Comment: Вы переобъявляете переменную `c`. В условиях вместо сравнения (`==`) присваивание (`=`). Обо всём этом вам уже сообщил компилятор.

Answer (score 1):

Компилятор вам сам подсвечивает ошибку.
Вы пытаетесь использовать оператор присваивания "=", когда нужно использовать оператор сравнения "=="

```
if(d==1) c = a+b; // Другие случаи сравнения аналогично
```

Также вы пытаетесь дважды определить переменную c - это ошибка